# Sticking Tooltip in Richfaces 4

Tags: javascript, richfaces

Does Richfaces 4 provides any built-in possiblity of a tooltip which sticks and allows the user to select text or click a link within the tooltip? The tooltip will be placed within a table.

- [Tooltip in Richfaces Showcase](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=tooltip)

Or did you have had this requirement as well and how did you solve it?

Comment: I don't get it, you posted the link to the showcase of exactly this usecase. What exactly do you want to know? Considering the table: be careful with https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-10971

Comment: @Thomas You asked in a suggested edit about why to edit at least 6 letters, [read the answer to this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81520/how-to-overcome-edits-must-be-at-least-6-characters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be the most simple example for an interactive tooltip.

```
<h:form>
<rich:panel>
<rich:tooltip followMouse="false" hideDelay="1500">
    <h:commandLink action="#{bean.doSomething()}" value="Do Something!" />
</rich:tooltip>
</rich:panel>
</h:form>
```

Comment: You also need to make sure the tooltip doesn't disappear when you move the mouse away from the panel trying to reach it. Either by setting a long `hideDelay` or `hideEvent="none"`.

Comment: @Makhiel good point! I edited my post. I think 1.5s should be enough to reach the tooltip and it won't be too annoying :)

Comment: Thank you. This solutions just have its disadvantage in moving fast over rows but in same column. ;-) I'm looking for a behaviour like here: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/coda-bubble.html (without the effects, don't need them). I hoped there is a solution with Richfaces itself. Looks like I do have to write an extension with jQuery.

Comment: I've implemented a solution (based on coda-bubble) by myself. I'll accept your answer since it will be the solution for most situation.